# Flutter widget which drag, rotate, zoom and not take any extra space

Tags: flutter, rotation, flutter-dependencies, drag, zoom-sdk

I have already try **matrix_gesture_detectox** its working in debug mode but not working in release mode in debug mode its rotating, zooming, dragging like everything what i want but not in release mode its not doing any thing. I not got any error in console in both debug and release.

The app is only for android.

My widget which i use

```
          MatrixGestureDetector(
            shouldRotate: true,
            shouldScale: true,
            onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
              setState(() {
                _matrix = tm * rm * sm * _matrix;
              });
            },
            child: Transform(
              transform: _matrix,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: height,
                width: width,
                child: Container(
                  key: childKey,
                  child: widget.child,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

I want rotation like other apps like with 2 fingers, zoom with 2 fingers, drag with 1 finger.
If you want any file code then i can provide you.

Comment: what do you see on the logs if you add `print(_matrix)`?

Comment: nothing in console already told there is no error in console

Comment: i am not talking about any error, i mean what do you see if you add that `print(_matrix)`?

Comment: I did not add ```print(_matrix)```